# Django web application and ways to flush cached media

Tags: django, caching, flush

I am working on a web application built using Django. It is already deployed and running from a while. Now i have to make some changes in JS files and CSS files. After making changes i can't see changes reflected on my application. Also i cant see the updated code in these files if i browse them. Though i can see the updated files are there on the server.

I removed the cookies in my browser without any luck. I am using firefox.

I cleared the django cache as well with the following suggested code:

```
from django.core.cache import cache
cache._cache.flush_all()
```

I also restarted the memcached server using:

```
service memcached restart.
```

I am using Centos as server side OS.

What other areas i need to look for cache flush?

Another thing i noticed: it automatically get flushed after some hours like 6+ hours. One file I uploaded almost 12 hours back and now i can see the changes are there. I have to make frequent changes in these files on the live environment but it is really stopping me to move forward. I am not allowed to pull the whole web application on my local environment so i have to stick with this working model.

Answer (score 1):

Flushing can by done with:

```
python3 manage.py clear_cache
```

You may also need to collect and compress the static files, as well as clear Django's cache of static files:

```
python3 manage.py collectstatic --noinput --clear
python3 manage.py compress --force
```

That will have to be done as a user with permission to the deployment directory, and so that the web service serving Django will have permission to read those.

The Django cache files can usually be seen in a directory like:

```
.../static/CACHE/css/
.../static/CACHE/js/
```

---

Side note:

It may better, if the system has `netcat`, to flush memcached without restarting it, since you said you are making changes to a production environment. Obviously, your situation is not ideal, but besides that. Django may throw `internal server error (500)` if it cannot use the cache when someone goes to the page.

```
echo 'flush_all' | netcat localhost 11211
```

Or whatever the memcached instance's port is.